# How to set up your database for a reddit-like user category subscription?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails, & I'm trying to setup my database for a website that lets users subscribe to channels, which will then populate that users homepage with content from the channels they are subscribed to.

I already have my user table, & my channel table. My first instinct would be to set up a 3rd database table like this:

subscriptions

```
user_id     channel_id
1            1
1            3
2            1
2            2
3            3
```

Is this the standard way to organize the database for a subscription/follow system?

Sorry if this seems like a dumb question, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: [has_many :through association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is. You basically thought of a join model, as this stores information that belongs to other models and has no meaning on its own. The advantages here is that Rails' Active Record gives you a lot of benefits by doing this.

You could set this 3 models up in rails doing the following:

Example using `Tennant`, `Property`, and `Invoice`

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :invoices, through: :properties
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :property
  has_many :tenants, through: :properties
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tenants, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :invoices, dependent: :destroy
end
```

As you see here, `Property` is my equivalent to your subscriptions. The advantages of setting your relations this way is AR support, if you create a new `Property` this will link a tenant with an invoice and insert a new record in the property table just with the id's of both involved models. Now when you ask AR for the first tennant you could also ask for the invoices:

```
Tennant.first.invoices
```

As they relate through the property. It would also help if you have a look at the generated query.